# Show B is invertible

Tags: matrices

I am assuming that $\lambda\neq0$ and $B$ is an $n \times n$ matrix such that $$B^3-2B^2-6B+\lambda I_n=O_{n,n}$$ Show that $B$ is invertible.

I know  that for B to be invertible then $\det(B)\neq0$. But I do not know where to go from here.

Comment: Of more use here is the identity $BB^{-1}=I$.

Comment: How do I apply this?

Comment: we haven't covered enough material for us to use eigenvalues like this.

Comment: Ignore the part about the eigenvalues and study the very first line of the answer to that question. Yours is solved in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have right at once the inverse:
$$B^3-2B^2-6B=-\lambda I\iff B\Bigl(-\tfrac1\lambda B^2+\tfrac2\lambda B+\tfrac6\lambda I\Bigr)=I.$$

Comment: how does this show it is invertible?

Comment: The product with another matrix is the unit matrix.